# Using Label Studio to create a dataset like CORD v2

Tags: dataset, ocr, labeling, label-studio, donut

I am using Label Studio to create a dataset for an OCR task to recognize items in a bunch of receipts. I am trying to use a pre-traiened model in Hugging Face named Donut which has been trained using CORD v2 dataset. [Here](https://github.com/clovaai/cord) is the link of the CORD documentation. I tried many templates and followed a lot of structure to label them as they have in CORD, but I did not managed to do so. Is there anyone who can write a script to label my dataset and create a JSON file introduced in the documentation or at least help me to find a good source to do so. Thanks

I tried OCR template in Label Studio as well as many tutorials in their website and youtube.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.